# function returning wrong response in python

Tags: python

as you can see from the text i am trying to call the function is_positive but everytime i test my code it returns neutral for all. all help is appreciated.

Code

```
def is_positive(review):
  return('neutral')
  if 'fun' in review:
    return('positive')
  if 'exciting' in review:
    return('positive')
  if 'friendly' in review:
    return('positive')
```

(tests)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(is_positive('It was lots of fun!'))
  print(is_positive('Such a friendly beekeeper!'))
  print(is_positive('Very exciting for the family.'))
  print(is_positive('My pizza was burnt.'))
```

Comment: The first line in your function is a return('neutral').  It seems like this line will be executed, and it will in fact return 'neutral'.

Answer (score 2):

The way the function is written right now, it immediately returns `neutral`. No checking of content of `review` is done before returning that value. To fix this, let's put the return statement at the end.

Here's a version that might achieve what you are after:

```py
def is_positive(review):
    if "fun" in review:
        return "positive"
    elif "exciting" in review:
        return "positive"
    elif "friendly" in review:
        return "positive"
    return "neutral"
```

Comment: I would rather use "or" in conditions, but why not, this works, +1

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_positive(review):
    if 'fun' in review or 'exciting' in review or 'friendly' in review:
        return 'positive'
    return 'neutral'
```

This code should work, you have to remove the first `return` to prevent the function to always end with return value `'neutral'`.

---

An better solution, as suggested in the comments, is this:

```
def is_positive(review: str) -> str:
    if any(x in review for x in ('fun', 'exciting', 'friendly')):
        return 'positive'
    return 'neutral'
```

You can also make it inline:

```
def is_positive(review: str) -> str: return 'positive' if any(x in review for x in ('fun', 'exciting', 'friendly')) else 'neutral'
```

---

If possible is a good practice to avoid putting `()` around the return value if it's a `str`ing, since it's unnecessary and what's more it may seem like a `tuple`.

Comment: also possible to use `if any(x in review for x in ('fun', 'exciting', 'friendly')):`, more useful when there are more words and they, perhaps, are stored somewhere as conditionals or something

Comment: Even better, I'll add it to my answer, I've always loved list comprenehsions.

Comment: it is a generator comprehension though, which should mean that it doesn't necessarily even check all of the words, but stops at the first one that is in there

Comment: I made it an inline if/else statement, it should work

Comment: you forgot `if`, and I wouldn't necessarily use a one-liner since it is a bit too long, but that's just me

Comment: You're right, I don't like too long lines too. Thank you anyway

Comment: ok, if you really wanted it in one line, then might as well put it all in one line: `def is_positive(review: str) -> str: return 'positive' if any(x in review for x in ('fun', 'exciting', 'friendly')) else 'neutral'`, but that is definitely too much